# How to declare an array of function pointers for functions with different arguments?

Tags: arrays, c, function, unit-testing, function-pointers

I am writing some tests for my project, and the functions have the same return type but a different number of parameters. I want to use an array of function pointers to call these test functions. How to declare an array of function pointers for such functions?

The functions are declared as:

```
bool test1();
bool test2(char const *string, uint32_t length);
```

Comment: Each function will need to have the same signature. Consider changing each test function to accept a `void *` to some arbitrary data which you can cast to the desired type inside each test function

Comment: How will you ensure that you are calling these functions with the correct number and type of arguments?

Comment: Try [`bool (array_of_function_pointers[100])()`.](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28array_of_function_pointers%5B100%5D%29%28%29)

Comment: @chux Clang says: *error : 'array_of_function_pointers' declared as array of functions of type 'bool ()'* (Maybe you forgot the `*` after the first `(`?) But, even then, [though it compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/PWe3EE7ss), I think you have UB.

Comment: You can explicitly convert any function pointer type to any other function pointer type and back again without change, but you must call the function using a function pointer type that is compatible with the function definition.

Comment: One (bad) solution is to typedef a function pointer like this: `typedef bool (*fp)();`. It has no information about the type of the arguments, so you could do `fp f1 = test1; f1();` and `fp f2 = test2; f2(some_string, some_length);`. Be aware that this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Zakk I'm not 100% sure about the undefined behaviour: if the caller and receiver function agree on the argument types and number, is it still UB?

Comment: @AdrianMole AFAIK, yes. Because it relies on your compiler's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that function pointers are not magic tricks, they still have to abide to the ABI calling convention, meaning that a function with a certain signature is intrinsically different from a function with a different signature.

Using a function pointer is more of a way to have dynamic methods, <strike>than to achieve polymorphism.</strike> EDIT: This is not polymorphism.

However, you can accomplish somewhat you ask by replacing each of the test functions to accept a `void*` and then code your parameters in a struct.

```
// Declare the test functions

//bool test1();
bool test1(void* struct_address)
{
    // struct address unused.
}

// Parameters for test2
struct test2{
    char const* string;
    uint32_t*   length;
}

//bool test2(char const *string, uint32_t length);
bool test2(void* struct_address)
{
    struct test2 test2_s = *(struct test2*)(struct_address);

    // Work with test2_s
}

// Declare the function pointer 
bool (*test_ptr)(void *);

// call test1
test_ptr = test1; test_ptr((void*)NULL);

// call test2
struct test2 test2_s = {param1,param2};
test_ptr = test2; test_ptr((void*)&test2_s);
```

Be careful because if you pass the wrong struct type you will get memory leaks and segmentation errors. Since this is a test environment, however, this can be mitigated.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for polymorphism.

Comment: Fixed. I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

In C, an empty parameter list in a function *declaration* does not mean that the function takes *no argument*; rather, it means that it takes an *unspecified number of arguments*.<sup>1</sup>

So, syntactically at least, you can specify an array of function pointers, each with an unspecified number of arguments (but a fixed return type), like this: `bool (*FnPtrArray[100])();`. You can then assign, to different elements of such an array, addresses of functions with different argument types and numbers. However, there can then be no compile-time check that those functions are called correctly, or any implicit conversion of given argument types to the 'correct' forms.

The code below illustrates this (but note that ***I do not recommend using code like this***, because of the inherent dangers that passing incorrect arguments can cause):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool Foo(int a) {
    printf("Foo: %d ...\n", a);
    return a % 2;
}

bool Bar(double x, double y) {
    printf("Bar: %5.3lf %5.3lf...\n", x, y);
    return x < y;
}

int main()
{
    bool (*FnPtrArray[100])();

    // So we can't tell at compile time which elements point where ...
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    int n = 42;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n % 2) {
        FnPtrArray[0] = Foo;
        FnPtrArray[1] = Bar;
    }
    else {
        FnPtrArray[1] = Foo;
        FnPtrArray[0] = Bar;
    }

    // Notes assuming given "n" is odd ...
    printf("%d\n\n", FnPtrArray[0](3));         // Works
    printf("%d\n\n", FnPtrArray[0](3.0));       // Wrong argument type
    printf("%d\n\n", FnPtrArray[1](1.0, 2.0));  // Works
    printf("%d\n\n", FnPtrArray[1](1, 2));      // Wrong argument types
    printf("%d\n\n", FnPtrArray[1](1.0));       // Wrong number of args

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a link to the above code on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYhBJDVIAB1QFQlsGZzcPPVj4mwFffyCWUPDIi0wrTIYhAiZiAmT3Ty4iksTyyoJswJCwiKiFCqqa1Pqelrbc/K6ASgtUV2Jkdg4AUgAmAGY/ZDcsAGoFlcce/FQAOgRd7AWNAEFltYYN123d/YJ0YNQXE7OL66u3ly2AGLvCB%2BAhbJjjHYAdgAQt8LgBOaLEUFUCDLJZA1AgHZLACs6C2R2JCzxjgYGNI4PGuzhV0RxEwBBmDHBuLxWyWtPhUIAIvDfu9aFsYZUIOhpsF6FtVFSJa4pZgtgBPSELWECpEowRojGi8LsvFHFa0KiG42m4lHUnkykyqmq7n0jQIxnM4is1Q7PYqp3XPkCy6grYsJh%2BCA0%2Bka50Iv7CiAAKgBDGUBGIl2IxCYytJMK4Gg0pN54wjfs1AHpy1shKgtgB3JWiBhgDhggjFYVMMFoFjROhKmxsIkkmPI1HopZLbCCMJshgdA0YmkrOk/BHBikrzUKJu6yfLAl25YANgYy9XiLwZogrIPnLV0bXiOTqfTmezucLeN53p/WLLLrPimaYZlmOZ4nmRa/iKlQAQi6r8jGxRKNCF6AS6L4ge%2B4GQd%2B0H/luMZAa%2BoEfhBX4/rsP76nBCGBoilZbAEqDtgo4IKAo7h%2BMAWzAHgABujC4ksFKTlseBsRghJWpqY46hOXL4ugNoUmSolLFSmFvmBn5FhAKzjOeiLGS6jEAOokAA1gosnagQe6KYeakqXaWmkThFH6UcGiGU68GmVWZnEAIPGVMA7iMG2yrRJgtnjhiB7Kc5zmTppwHaWRuG8hAXDeVSSzeb5hEIuZVk2aOdkOYlLkpRpgLpe5uZcHp9T3kZ6ElYFwVGOCxDhWwghbAQ0WYOVa5yfZCnVcltqpfVJHYU1LWFe1/mdVsQUhVs855LOqBmmFY2am6LJbIWhH%2BohlwcJMtCcHivCeBwWikNiHCOFsCjTLMSo3DwpAEJoN2TJZIArLlUIFpIAAcCLQ3iKwaJIkQIis%2BicJIj1A69nC8AoIBRIDz03aQcCwDAiAoKgvb9mQFAQD2fb0OEyDAFwXAaTQtDtsQ%2BMQME2PBH4lTKpw/09gNBAAPIMLQovE6QWChkY4gK/gjLWAJo3Y5gqiYMgrjttjoLFNjtB4MEWbEMqzhYNjaZ4CwYsk1QBjAAoABqeCYHWUsxU9L38IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOoCu6PUBhGCApjGOY5vBPjkCTKg0SlPjHAALRmWIwqFzF6CGDYyB48U%2BulPYDBOC4tReA3IwLmkcQJAI/R1DEnelG3u3hIMNeawIzR9E3AwNLXTS9K0fjtEPehDJPKS96vC85O3XCTF9MxzHoaaYPMPC3fdWMK29qjQ8e%2BfHpIvHIMgWzs0cSxbBAjhUrghAkLi4MqTOBpszABu9eBEy0JMCASBGa03IJQOBzMUBsw5nwOgPM%2BYCwVkLZg1tnakAlpFGWctsZK0MMAVWL11az0EnnF6ut9aG3mC9E2d0FZpytjbDALCIEoidtwF2btPbe19v7bGQdhCiHEOHSRUc1DY10GjBOJgzD6AthnCMr0c6JDztXRodgIAOB7i3dAg8xj1HSF3JIU9e5WIHovUYnQR4GLKPPExLjZ7j3nuY5xFh3G2JXj4xxO897fUPvUY%2Bp8SbsIeqQAOvBr633vo/YAz9X65Q/l/H%2B%2BAiDEDAUA6mTNZw3AMhAoGhlSAIEwEwLA4QtHsMxqQJ2kgjTQxWB0zpXSOnSASTjDgeMCYAwqaTCmMCQDTAINEQ2CCGZFNpgEVg8wb7HhDAofiL9%2BJcARMaf6mBckkDwOgPQkiQ4yOkHIpQCjY56DrFmaIztz4cDiX0t6UtDbTLBPtGUySH5Pxfm/LJwDin5L%2BuMcpxNoFIEmZ82Z%2By/4omOfUU50iw4XNkPImOL0lGkDuUwB5ginkvOxm8j5hstjfJWSk/5GT36f2BbTABZThmQqeU0p2eJJBHC4MeXlfL%2BV8t6SS3GFgj4VJBiAY80N34IgRHifMUhjxyrxAiDS7CViXxem9CFUCnlLF4E7fMURXkisgcDUggleaJAiEAA%3D%3D), for those who want to test with various compilers and settings.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is very different from C++, where an empty formal parameter list *does* mean no argument.

Comment: This can cause UB.

Comment: Aaaah and that `scanf("%d", &n)`.... Imagine someone who enters "Too bad for you!!"

Comment: @Zakk Possibly/probably. A citation from the Standard confirming that would be nice. (But I'm off to do a bit off ruminating, and I may just delete this answer if I feel that it is giving poor advice.)

Comment: @Zakk OK, I'll take that! Edited to give `n` an initial value.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60685871/16835308).

Comment: Actually, I think my opening line (2nd paragraph) here is wrong. It's *not* a prototype but a definition of an array of pointers to functions with a `void` argument list. That's what MSVC makes of it; but clang waits until the first use and takes the signature from that. I'll wait a bit for the big guns to possibly clarify.

Comment: Why not ask a separate question?

Comment: @Zakk Yes, indeed. I'm on mobile now, so not easy to do  but maybe bit later.

Comment: Let me know when you ask it. For e.g. can you put the link here?

Comment: @AdrianMole yes, please post the link here for that question.

Comment: This is not a good practice. Calling a function declared with an empty parameter list performs the default argument promotions, so it may improperly call functions defined in other ways, such as `bool foo(char c)`, resulting in behavior not defined by the C standard. A defined way to store function addresses and call the functions is to convert them all to any common arbitrary function pointer type and then convert each back to its defined type when calling it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I know it's not good practice (for many reasons). I have tried, in my answer, to address the issue of default argument conversions (and my example demonstrates that failure, when using `1` and `2` as a potential/intended `double` arguments - though maybe not clearly enough). But is this UB? Put another way, what is the "type" of an element of the `FnPtrArray` ?

Comment: @AdrianMole: The particular functions in this code work with the examples shown that are labeled as working, and that is because these particular functions have arguments of type `int` and `double`, which are the types that result from the default argument promotions applied to the arguments shown in those calls. However, if a function defined as `bool foo(char c) { … }` were called with a pointer in `FnPtrArray`, which has type “pointer to function with no prototype returning `bool`”, says as `FnPtrArray[0](0)`, the behavior would be undefined per C 2018 6.5.2.2 6, which says…

Comment: … “… If … the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined…” Since `0` is `int` after promotion, and `int` is not compatible with `char`, the behavior would be undefined. However, if the call were made with a conversion first, as in `((bool (*)(char))FnPtrArray[0])(0)`, that would be fine. That makes the expression used to call the function have a type that includes a prototype, so the `int` argument would be converted to `char`, and the behavior would be defined by 6.5.2.2 7.